# Maximizing $x^T A^T B \, x$ over the unit Euclidean sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Is there an algorithm to solve the QCQP

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^T A^T B \, x\\ \text{subject to} & \|x\|_2 = 1\end{array}$$

when $A^T B$ is *not* necessarily symmetric? When $A^T B$ is symmetric, there is a simple solution. However in this context I do not know how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming $A$, $B$ being quadratic matrices ? Not in general. Probably you want to maximize for  $x$ with $||x||\leq 1$ or other boundary conditions ?

Comment: This question doesn't seem well-written. a) Don't you mean $(Ax)^T(Bx)$? b) By "is this possible" do you mean 'is there an algorithm'? OP you can hardly expect people to put effort into answering your question if you don't put effort into writing it.

Comment: Yes, $||x|| =1$ here is a boundary condition.

Comment: Much better. Thank you for the edit!

Comment: Maximizing $x^TQx$ is equivalent to maximizing $\frac{1}{2}x^T(Q + Q^T)x$ so if you know how to maximize the symmetric case, you have the non-symmetric case already.

Comment: I would start googling about "maximize the Rayleigh quotient". There is much stuff if $A^TB$ form hermitian matrices (rendering the eigenvalues as bounds).